# Ruby on Rails - Crear calendario desde cero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

Como parte de mi proyecto, necesitaría crear un calendario que mostrara las semanas de dos en dos, en vez de mensualmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna pista? El usuario no debería poder crear eventos. Solo poder seleccionar un slot disponible o no.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: yo buscaría una gema que pueda ajustar a mis necesidades, al menos para no tener que crear la estructura del calendario.

Answer (score 2):

Me respondo a mi mismo.

[Simple_calendar](https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar/) y [Table Builder](https://github.com/carouselapps/table_builder) parecen poder hacer lo que necesito.

Espero que pueda servirle a otra persona.

Comment: Si te funcionó acepta la respuesta.